# Traditional machine learning algorithms for time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

Are there machine learning algorithms that can handle temporal data as a sequence?  I am trying to avoid any deep learning models like RNN/LSTM/GRU etc... due to data size/lack of GPU

Ex.

```
time, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3
1     25         150        0.7       
2     25.3       147        1.1        
3     25.5       145        0.8
...
10    26.7       165        1.2
```

Now I want to predict feature_1 at time 10 using the first 3 time steps of all features using a dataset like this

```
feature_1,       feature_2,       feature_3,       target
[25,25.3,25.5]   [150,147,145]    [0.7,1.1,0.8]    26.7
```

Comment: Markov Chains are quite "traditional," if you want to avoid neural networks.

Comment: What is the size of the data? Using a NN like an LSTM doesn't see significant acceleration with GPU, so CPU is likely sufficient for training.

Answer (score 0):

[Autoregressive models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) and its variations are quite famous for time-series forecasting, there is even a python library [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html).

I remember facebook once released model for time-series forcasting as well, never used it though. Maybe you can have a look at it, its called [`Prophet`](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api).